# How to filter url on post submission?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, filters, regex, post-content

I would like to swap out image URLs upon post submission on both `content editor` field and a custom field `cover_image` of a custom post type `article`.

For example, the original content may contain image url such as:

```
<img src="http://original-domain.com/gallery/2016/01/01/filename.jpg">
```

I would like to swap it to:

```
<img src="http://new-domain.com/album/20160101/filename.jpg">
```

And have it stored permanently to the database.

How to edit the regular expression is not my concern, but where to make the edit to insert the regular expression is what would like to know.

Is there some kind of filter that I can use on post submission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`save_post` didn't work for me.

What works in my situation is using [content_save_pre](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/content_save_pre) filter or the content processing before save.

Since I'm using `Advanced Custom Field` plugin for my `cover_image` field, and I ended up using `acf/save_post` filter to process the field.

Comment: That's pretty cool, considering your question made no reference to ACF.

Answer (score 1):

[`image_send_to_editor`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/image_send_to_editor/) hook will handle when the image is sent to the editor. The problem will be that your editor may not work correctly when you modify the URL -- use with caution.

[`save_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) will allow you to modify the `$post` content on save.

[`update_(meta_type)_metadata`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/update_(meta_type)_metadata) could be used to intercept when the meta data is saved.